# How to choose the right words in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, grep

how to use grep to get numbers that will not contain 3 and 7, not strings!

I try that

```
 grep -o '[[:digit:]^37]*' test
```

but its not work

Comment: Can you add a few lines of sample input and exact expected output for those lines? Also try to explain in more details what you want the command to do.

Comment: Does this help - `\b[01245689]+\b`?

Comment: @Sundeep, source text 

`hello, world nan

hello,68
 
world

a2e

sad

f

123

345

456

678

dtdfstgvc5

23

ds3`

answer `68 456`

Comment: @AKSingh, I don't have to list all the allowed numbers, because the task can be transferred to letters

Comment: @Shrek1995. Please edit the question to mention how you want the output. The regex I provided returns `68 and 456`. What is the problem then?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a GNU `grep`, you can use

```sh
grep -oP '\b[^\D37]+\b' file
```

The `grep -oP '\b[^[:^digit:]37]+\b'` is a synonymic command.
*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary (may be replaced with `(?<!\d)` if you simply want to make sure there are no other digits immediately on the left)
- `[^` - start of a negated bracket expression that matches chars other than:

  - `\D` - any non-digit char
  - `37` - `3` and `7`
- `]+` - end of the bracket expression, repeat one or more times
- `\b` - a word boundary (may be replaced with `(?!\d)` if you simply want to make sure there are no other digits immediately on the right).

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/SzJaYX):

```sh
s='123 456 857 112 i21.'
grep -oP '\b[^\D37]+\b' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
456
112
```

To use the same approach for letters, relace `\D` with `\P{L}` or `[:^digit:]` with `[:^alpha:]`.